# Undefined reference to symbol 'acs_map' when running makeconfig

Tags: kernel, compiling

I get a linker error when I try to configure the Linux kernel with `menuconfig`:

```
# make menuconfig
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/mconf
/usr/local/bin/ld: scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/checklist.o: undefined reference to symbol 'acs_map'
/usr/local/bin/ld: note: 'acs_map' is defined in DSO /lib/libtinfo.so.5 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/libtinfo.so.5: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/mconf] Error 1
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Any idea as to what is wrong with it? I'm running CentOS 6.2 and I'm sure I've installed all the needed libs.

Comment: did you install all of these:"gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel"?

Comment: Yep. ncusrses, binutils, and more. ;/

Comment: Which version of curses?

Answer (score 8):

After upgrading binutils to 2.22 I ran into the same issue. I solved it by adding the following line to *scripts/kconfig/Makefile*:

```
HOSTLOADLIBES_mconf     = -ltinfo
```

Apparently a change in the linker no longer includes libraries for you for free anymore; you must explicitly link against every library your application needs. See the following for more information: [DSO link change](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange)

For 3.2.58 kernel append the `-ltinfo` to the end of the `HOSTLOADLIBES_mconf` line, so the original:

```
HOSTLOADLIBES_mconf   = $(shell $(CONFIG_SHELL) $(check-lxdialog) -ldflags $(HOSTCC))
```

will become:

```
HOSTLOADLIBES_mconf   = $(shell $(CONFIG_SHELL) $(check-lxdialog) -ldflags $(HOSTCC)) -ltinfo
```

Comment: I honestly don't know how I'd do my job without SO and it's brethren sometimes. Thank you @sfpiano!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to symlink between libncurses.so. and libtinfo.so.?

```
cd /lib
ln -s /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5 /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5
```

The libncurses lib name may depend on you version.

Answer (score 0):

In 5.X.Y and later kernels I have been modifying `HOSTLDLIBS_mconf` in the file scripts/kconfig/Makefile to:

`HOSTLDLIBS_mconf = $(shell . $(obj)/mconf-cfg && echo $$libs) -ltinfo`

works on my Centos 6.8 machine.